# Download an MP3 from server and play multiple times (loop). Multiple downloads?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, audio-streaming

I have a simple button that plays a small MP3 file, looping it 30 times. The MP3 is streamed from a server (urlMP3).

I can see on my Galaxy S2 that it accesses the server for each of the 30 loops. Is it downloading the MP3 each time it loops or downloading once and playing from the phone's memory?

```
//Button 'audioYes' to play audio loop x 30
var soundLoop:Sound = new Sound();
var soundChannel:SoundChannel;
var soundLoopUrl:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlMP3);

audioYes.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f2_MouseClickHandler);

function f2_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    soundLoop.load(soundLoopUrl);
    soundLoop.play(0, 30);
}
```

If it is downloading each time, what would be a good way to download it once and then play? Thanks for your help.

Edit: Sep 1 2012
I've created a simple flash file and added the following provided by @Rytis. I'm getting an error from the last line, this.mySound.play "Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." What do I do with that?

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.display.Loader;

var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var myurlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

myurlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.onSoundLoadComplete)
myurlLoader.load(new URLRequest("01.mp3"))

function onSoundLoadComplete(event:Event):void{
this.mySound = URLLoader(event.target).data as Sound;
this.mySound.play(0,30);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - download sound and store it to variable before playing it.

Example:

```
package {
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

public class SoundLoadTest {

    protected var sound     : Sound;

    public function SoundLoadTest () {

        var urlLoader : URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        urlLoader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, this.onSoundLoadComplete )
        urlLoader.load( new URLRequest( "path/to/sound.file" ) )

    }

    protected function onSoundLoadComplete ( event : Event) : void {

        // save loaded sound to a class field
        this.sound = URLLoader( event.target ).data as Sound;

        // start playing sound
        this.sound.play( 0, 30 );

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rytis Will this continue to store the sound in the phone, because the user gets a new sound each day, for a month. Will it accumulate?

Comment: No, it won't. If you need to store it on the phone then when sound is downloaded you should write it to a file and every time you run you application you should check if if that sound is already downloaded.

Comment: Getting an error at this.sound.play( 0, 30 ); Please see edit above. Thx